# How to get the laravel route name on js

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hello guys I have search and I didnt find anything, do you know how to get a laravel route name on js?

For example on php we can do `$name = Route::currentRouteName();`

Comment: Get it in PHP/Blade and add it to a variable in a `<script>` tag

Comment: @brombeer Thats what I am trying but i need to include the Route class on blade?

Comment: Nope; `Route` is an alias and is available in views without need to import. You can do `var currentRouteName = '{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}';`, or use a `data-attribute` as illustrated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your layout.blade.php

```
<body data-page="{{ Route::currentRouteName() }}">
    @yield('content')

    <script>
        var currentRouteName = document.body.dataset.page;
    </script>
</body>
```

If you for some reason don't like injecting stuff in your DOM just to read it with JavaScript, you can do something else:

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('your-route', function() {
    return response()
        ->view('your-view', compact('your-data'))
        ->header('route-name', 'your-route');
})->name('your-route');
```

your-view.blade.php

```js
var req = fetch(document.location, {
    'method': 'OPTIONS'
}).then((res) => alert(res.headers.get('route-name')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Ziggy, this npm package helps to integrate Laravel named routes with your frontend, with it you can easely get current route name and even acces routes for all your application endpoint just like you would do with Laravel:

https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

Examples From the Documentation:

```
//app.js
//get current route name
// Route called 'events.index', with URI '/events'
// Current window URL is https://ziggy.test/events

route().current();               // 'events.index'

// routes/web.php
Route::get('posts/{post}', fn (Request $request, Post $post) => /* ... */)->name('posts.show');

// app.js
route('posts.show', 1); // 'https://ziggy.test/de/posts/1'
```